# phpExcel : Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: php, phpexcel

I actualy use phpExcel to get an excel file that i recover from the user with an `<input type='file'>` and after i convert this excel file in csv file.

My script work and the csv file is generate. The problem is after my script finish the page never stop to loading and i get this error in my console : `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`.

Their is another problem i use also an other object in my script for display the menu and the menu don't display is i use PHPExcel.

Their is my code for call my PHPExcel object creation :

```
<?php
///Get excelFile ///        
if(isset($_FILES['excelFileCandidat']))
{
   require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../lib/ExcelCandidat/ExcelCandidat.class.php";
   $file = new ExcelCandidat($_FILES['excelFileCandidat']);
   $file->excelFileToCsv();
}



echo "<table width='100%'>";
echo     "<tr>";
echo        "<td>";
echo           "Import new Excel File : ";
echo           "<input type='file' name='excelFileCandidat' />";
echo        "</td>";
echo        "<td>";
echo           "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Send' />";
echo        "</td>";
echo     "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

And my object :

```
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/../PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php";

class ExcelCandidat
{
    private $excelFile;
    public function __construct($file)
    {
        $this->excelFile = $file;
    }

    public function excelFileToCsv()
    {
        set_time_limit(600);
        if (!is_array($this->excelFile))
        {
             throw new Exception("STR_APPROCHECK_ERR");
        }

        $newFilename = 'csvCandidat';
        $ext = strrchr($this->excelFile['name'], '.');
        $isExcel = stripos($ext, '.xls') !== false;
        if($isExcel) 
        {
            ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
            $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($this->excelFile['tmp_name']);
            $worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
            $writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel , 'CSV');
            $writer->setDelimiter(';');
            $writer->setEnclosure('"');
            $writer->setUseBOM(false);
            $tmpName = dirname(__FILE__) . '/file/' . $newFilename . date('ymdHis') .'.csv';
            $writer->save($tmpName);
            unset($objPHPExcel, $writer);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: The problem come from the line $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($this->excelFile['tmp_name']); because when i comment everything except this line the problem persist

Comment: What is weird is that the script enter in the other object and pass everything but my echo don't work. I'm lost.

Comment: I just try on another computer and the problem disapear so i think it's a configuration problem i actualy use wamp 2.2 with php 5.2.7. But i still have the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the problem come from the library in the file PHPExcel/Calculation.php.

You have to add a line at the begin of the class PHPExcel_Calculation add a line `private $saveThis;` and in the construct function(line 1722) add a `line $this->saveThis = $this;` and in the destruct function (line 1740) remplace `$this` by `$saveThis`

Comment: You don't want to be changing the phpexcel library.

Comment: Like it correct my problem yea it's what i will do.

Comment: Well obviously you can, but if you decide to update PHPExcel, it might not work anymore. Or you might find using other parts of the library won't work anymore

Comment: It's ok if you look what i correct their is no way that it could have an incidence on other part of the development becuase it's just a problem with php object that i resolve sometime $this don't take the good object i can't remember why but i know it's append so i just save $this at the construct of the object and use it in destruct function.